# Error : on a null object reference, SavedInstanceState rotation recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to create savedInstanceState that will save/keep data when display is rotating landscape or portrait, but it keep crashing when i try to rotate the display, and showing error "on a null object reference,

Here is some code for my Adapter :

```
public class ListMovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListMovieAdapter.CardViewViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Movie.ResultsBean> listMovie;
ProgressDialog progressBar;

public ListMovieAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie.ResultsBean> listMovie) {
    this.listMovie = listMovie;
    this.context = context;
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
}

public ArrayList<Movie.ResultsBean> getListMovie() {
    return listMovie;
}

public void setListMovie(ArrayList<Movie.ResultsBean> movieList) {
    this.listMovie = movieList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and here is some of my Fragment code :

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {
View v;
private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
private Parcelable mRecyclerState;
private ListMovieAdapter listMovieAdapter;
private ArrayList<Movie> listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Movie.ResultsBean>> dataMovies = new MutableLiveData<>();
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
public static String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org";
public static String CATEGORY = "upcoming";
public static int PAGE = 1;
public static String API_KEY = "ce7feeb6af94d9372180d04db1bc755d";
public static String LANGUAGE = "en-US";
private static final String SAVEINSTANCE_RECYCLERSTATE = "RecyclerState";
private static final String SAVEINSTANCE_LIST = "movielist";

public MovieFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie, viewGroup, false);
    myrecyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_fragmovie);
    myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fetchJSON();
}else{
    mRecyclerState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVEINSTANCE_RECYCLERSTATE);
    listMovieAdapter.setListMovie((ArrayList)savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(SAVEINSTANCE_LIST));
    myrecyclerview.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mRecyclerState);
}
    return v;
}

private void fetchJSON() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Movie> call = apiInterface.listOfMovie(CATEGORY, API_KEY, LANGUAGE, PAGE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Movie>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
            Movie results = response.body();
            List<Movie.ResultsBean> listMovie = results.getResults();
            ListMovieAdapter listMovieAdapter = new ListMovieAdapter(getContext(),
                    (ArrayList<Movie.ResultsBean>) listMovie);
            myrecyclerview.setAdapter(listMovieAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Movie> call, Throwable t) {
            showDialogLoad(false);
            showDialogFail(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mRecyclerState = myrecyclerview.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable(SAVEINSTANCE_RECYCLERSTATE,mRecyclerState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(SAVEINSTANCE_LIST,(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) listMovieAdapter.getListMovie());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and then some error log :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.ilham.mymoviecatalogue.adapter.ListMovieAdapter.getListMovie()' on a null object reference
    at com.ilham.mymoviecatalogue.fragment.MovieFragment.onSaveInstanceState(MovieFragment.java:106)
```

Comment: What variable has the null value?  Look at the logcat to see where the exception is happening.

Comment: @NormR there is "ListMovieAdapter.getListMovie()" sir, and i don't really know how to fix it

Comment: `return listMovie;` Make sure it returning the list.

Comment: Why are there two variables named: listMovieAdapter. One at the class level and one local to a method.  Does the class level variable ever get a value?

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variables 
`private static final String SCROLL_POSITION = "SCROLL_POSITION";`
`private RecyclerView movieGrid;`
`private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;`

For onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt(SCROLL_POSITION, ((LinearLayoutManager)movieGrid.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
        }
```

Then below that add:

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        final int position = savedInstanceState.getInt(SCROLL_POSITION);
        movieGrid.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                movieGrid.scrollToPosition(position);
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Note, the last number `300` should be adjusted accordingly, to test if it is returning to the position you were last in instead of resetting your position to the top upon rotation.